# Select N-Channel MOSFET to drive speaker and LEDs

Tags: mosfet, pwm, circuit-design, mosfet-driver

I have 3 circuits with [MOSFET](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/2N7002BKW.pdf) gates routed to [MCU's](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/b5/24/80/11/51/59/47/f7/DM00141136.pdf/files/DM00141136.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00141136.pdf) PWM / IO and I would like to drive with them a [Speaker](http://www.puiaudio.com/pdf/SMT-0540-S-R.pdf), [RGY LED](https://www.bivar.com/portals/0/products/SMTL4-RGY.pdf) and [Backlight of LCD](http://www.newhavendisplay.com/specs/NHD-C12832A1Z-FSW-FBW-3V3.pdf).

There's a lot of parameters in MOSFET's datasheet. I am not sure if this is the right MOSFET for each of the circuits here. Can you help me to determine if this is the right MOSFET?

I have chosen the MOSFET by Vgs(fit to MCU max Voh), max Vds and Ids.

Speaker circuit: [image]

LED circuit: [image]

LCD backlight circuit:[image]

Thank you.

Comment: they will probably work, but it seems like Rds is kinda high (1.6Ω). unless you're getting a great deal on them i would keep looking at more logic level FETs.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is not 4 ohms, it is 12 ohms. The resistor in series with the speaker is not 6 ohms, it is 150 ohms so the power in the tiny speaker is 0.0048W and it will not be heard.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your Gate signal will also be in the 3.3V range? From Figures 6 and 8, you will see the turn on resistance is pretty high with \$V_{GS}\$ = 3.3V.  That might be okay for the LEDs; say they had a \$V_f\$ of 2.2V, then; $$(3.3V - 2.2V)/.01A = 110 ohms$$ that will be shared between \$R_{DS}\$ of the MOSFET and the series resistor.

For the Speaker, let's say it is 4 ohms. Then; $$3.3V/(4 ohm + 6 ohm )(R_{DS}, Fig 6  = 0.33A)$$
\$P=I^2R\$, so \$.33 \cdot .33 \cdot 4 = 0.4W\$ max, so the volume won't be terribly loud, best case.